# How to create Android VectorDrawables from Illustrator (or similar tool)?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

If I have a vector image in a program like Illustrator, how can I end up with the correct format for Android's VectorDrawable framework to use?

I found a tool to convert SVG to the VectorDrawable xml format: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/
but it requires SVGs only use "path".

Any ideas how to output files like that?

Comment: Use a library that processes **REAL SVG** files, like android-svg, svg-android or any of your liking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That tool only appears to currently support `<path>` elements.  So for example it doesn't support `<rect>`, `<circle>` etc.

If you are using primitives like this in your drawing, you need to convert them.  I forget the exact option you need to use, but it's probably something like "Convert to path".

This link may help.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/convert-primitive-to-path-using-svg-format-in-illustrator

Comment: Important note - we were having a problem with things that were already 'path' elements in the SVG not looking right in Android, and we resolved it by doing what that link says (and @dom says) even on the items that AI was already exporting to SVG path elements.  So as a blanket statement, do this for all objects before exporting to SVG, then use svg2android.

Answer (score 47):

If you're using Android Studio, the best method is:

- Right-click on your 'drawable' folder > New > Vector Asset
- Click 'Local SVG file' to import your own SVG file, or 'Material Icon' to use the supplied icons.
- Change the resource name to whatever you need it to be.
- Click Next and choose your target modules and res directory.
- Click Finish.

The wizard produces XML from your SVG files.

Comment: The Vector Asset studio was added to Android Studio in the v1.4.0 release, which was September 2015. All the other answers were prior to this update.

Comment: is it possible to invoke this from terminal, makefile, gradle, etc.? I would like to store only svg (as I need it for ios project too) and generate vector drawable in the build time.

Comment: You might want to select the "Override" checkbox for the dimensions.

Answer (score 13):

Just use [SVG to VectorDrawable Converter](https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter) or its [online version](http://svg2vector.com). This is a batch converter of SVG images to Android VectorDrawable XML resource files.

Link points to readme, which provide enough information on how to use the converter.

Comment: I and another developer both couldn't get that tool to work properly and provide good output, sorry.  I had great success with the tool "svg2android" though - http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Answer (score 12):

#### Convert Everything into Paths

Before saving your AI project file as an `SVG`, make sure you:

1. Convert all paths to outlines, using `Object > Expand...`.
2. Convert any shape paths (such as `<circle>`) to `Compound Paths` by right-clicking while you have the object/s selected, and choosing `Make Compound Path`.

Once that's done each shape in the SVG should be a `<path>`.

---

#### Optimise the SVG

When I tried to convert an SVG of medium complexity to a vector drawable using the app mentioned in the question, I had issues with it forgetting some parts. I figured it must have something to do with the way it's formatted, so I decided to use [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), an SVG optimisation app, to strip it down to its bare essentials.

Use SVGOMG, or another app, to optimise the SVG, and then download the file.

---

#### Convert the Optimised SVG into a Vector Drawable

Take the downloaded SVG and drop it into [SVG2Android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) and it will give you what you're after.